# Android: open the local database from the emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, batch-file

I have my .db file on my android file explorer: data/data/myapplication/databases

Can you please tell me how can I open this file for exemple with the mozilla SqliteManager.
Normaly, I should be qble to copy my .db file from the project to my harddrive with a .bat file, but how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean EMULATION instead of simulator??

Comment: I meant emulator too )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using `eclipse`, go to `ddms/file explorer` and find ur file and pull it to your hard drive. later u can view it through `sqlite browser`

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answer.
I am using Eclipse and I am on a green android icon file explorer but I have no possibility to do anything with my .db file, when i touch him or try to pull him, nothing happens.